# How to change asp.net mvc5 web app current localization culture with refreshing the same page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, localization

I want to change localization culture of the project with refreshing the current page only. To do this, i want to put two href to the layout.I tried a lot to getting current request both view and controller but i did not achieve this.
My route config as below;

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            constraints: new { lang = @"(\w{2})|(\w{2}-\w{2})" },
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",Lang="tr", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Also my attribute as below;

```
public class LocalizationAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{

    private string _DefaultLanguage = "tr";

    public LocalizationAttribute(string defaultLanguage)
    {
        _DefaultLanguage = defaultLanguage;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string lang = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] ?? _DefaultLanguage;
        if (lang != _DefaultLanguage)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(String.Format("ERROR: Invalid language code '{0}'.", lang));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

when i try to use

```
 <a href='@Url.Action("ChangeLanguage","Home",new { @lang="tr",@returnurl=this.Request.RawUrl})'>Türkçe</a>
```

or sth like that, parameters disappearing or the url not showing sometimes like Index actions ? Is there any way to refresh exactly same page with only changing the "lang" of the route?

Comment: why don't you use current `controller, action, id` params in your `Url.Action` ?

Comment: @teran could you please clarify this ?The href is in layout and the method ChangeLanguage is changing the culture.The problem is about redirecting the same action

Comment: I mean, why do you use `ChangeLanguage` route instead of generating link to the current page for required `lang`. you can take current `controller, action, id` values  from `RouteData` and build href for them with required `lang` directly

Comment: @teran thank you i understand now really thank you, what if i put this to layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while your routes contain only one default route `lang, controller, action, id` params in URL you can use code like snippet below to add links for different cultures in _layout.

```
    @{
        var locales = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "en", "eng" }, { "ru", "rus" } };            

        var controller = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        var action = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        var id = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];

    }
    <ul id="changeLang">            
        @foreach (var l in locales) {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(l.Value, action, controller, new { lang = l.Key, id = id}, null)</li>
        }
    </ul>
    @RenderBody()
```

but this approach work fine only for `Default`-route pattern. When you add other params to request it will not work.

**update**
as an option, you can generate links on the client side, using jquery and the knowledge of current lang, but you should white correct rexep to replace lang.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var locales = [{ key: 'ru', title: 'rus' }, { key: 'en', title: 'eng' }];

        var cl = '@Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"]';
        var curl = '@Request.RawUrl';
        var rexp = new RegExp("\/{LANG}\/?".replace("/{LANG}/", cl), "i");

        $.each(locales, function (idx, l) {
            var link = $("<a>").attr("href", curl.replace(rexp, l.key)).text(l.title);
            $("ul#jlang").append($("<li>").append(link));
        });
    });
</script>
```

**update 2**
mixed server side and client side code:

1. render locales menu at server side

   ```
   @{
       var locales = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "en", "eng" }, { "ru", "rus" } };
   }
   <ul id="changeLang">            
       @foreach (var l in locales) {
           <li><a href="#" id="@l.Key">@l.Value</a></li>
       }
   </ul>
   ```
2. change url at client side

   ```
       $("#changeLang a").click(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var tl = $(this).attr("id");
           var cl = '@Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"]';
           var rexp = new RegExp("\/{LANG}\/?".replace("/{LANG}/", cl), "i");            

           window.location = window.location.href.replace(rexp, tl);
       });
   ```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I have tried sth like this. Unfortunately, i have something different params some pages

Comment: @mayk may be better solution will be using jquery and build link on the client side replacing `lang` in url

Comment: i will try this thanks again for the suggestions. I will update this post if i achieve before i die :)

Comment: IT WORKS PERFECT!! Thank you. You saved my life :)

Comment: The update code is really perfect it works every parameters on every url. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @mayk you are welcome. Actually, may be better solution will be mix both approaches. At server side you can render list of locales with empty `href`, and then add jquery `.click` handler which will change url and navigate to it